# Scanf for not the same amount of data in C

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

I am trying write a code for program in C, but i found a problem i am not able to solve. I get a set of input, but the input is not always the same. How do i use scanf to read not always the same amount of data?

Input 1):

```
+ 12345 Lala
```

Input 2):

```
- 12345
```

If i use something like this:

```
scanf("%s %d %s", a[i], &b[i], c[i]);
```

the terminal requests more data for me (which i understand). So how do i use scanf to sometimes read all three (string, integer, string) and sometimes just two (string, integer)?

Comment: Use something like `fgets` to read the whole line into a buffer, then you may use `sscanf` to parse its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by reading the whole line

```
char line[100];

scanf(" %[^\n]", line);
```

or

```
fgets(line, 100, stdin);
```

Then use [sscanf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm) to read the values from the line.

```
int itemsRead = sscanf(line, "%s %d %s", a[i], &b[i], c[i]);
```

The return value of sscanf will tell you how many values you successfully read from the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try fgets:

```
 char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes